# How to customise both choices and description of a debconf question?

Tags: bash, scripts, packaging, configure, debconf

I'm currently working on a package script where I need to provide customised choices and also wish to provide an extended description based on those choices.

I've successfully modified a Linux installer before with a preseed and custom scripts using Debconf to ask questions so I am familiar with how it works.

Where I am stuck is changing the description in the template. According to all the Debconf manuals I looked up online both choices and description can be customised, although the information is brief. There are plenty of examples customising Choices with `db_subst` and this works fine.

Where I am stuck is customising the Description text and in this case the extended description. I've tried using `db_subst` but with no satisfactory results. The problem is I need to extend the description with more lines of text. But I've found Debconf only uses one line. If I put newline markers like "\n" in text it interprets them literally which looks messed up.

Can Debconf be programmed to customise a Description with a few extra lines of text? Or do I need to give up and just create a customised template file by hand for this one question? I see I may have gone beyond the features of what Debconf provides but to me it didn't seem so complicated.

Here is my example script and template so you can see how and what I have done to test it.

```
#!/bin/sh

# testing.sh 
# Debconf testing script.
# Testing dynamic changing of choices and description in question.

export DEBCONF_DEBUG=developer
#export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=gnome

. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule

db_x_loadtemplatefile ./testing.template testing
db_settitle testing/title

list="1, 2, 3, 4"
extended="One\n Two\n Three\n Four\n"

# Use real newlines in text
#extended=`echo "${extended}"`

db_subst testing/list list "${list}"
db_subst testing/list extended "${extended}"
db_reset testing/list
db_input critical testing/list 
db_go
db_get testing/list

db_stop

exit 0


# testing.template

Template: testing/title
Type: title
Description: Testing title

Template: testing/list
Type: select
Choices: ${list}
Description: Please select option below.
 Extended description.
 .
 ${extended}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add actual newlines to your variable, like this:

```
extended="One
Two
Three
Four"
```

This took some experimentation on my part.  The Debian [debconf-devel](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/debconf-doc/debconf-devel.7.en.html) manual says

> Notice that: - Like in a debian package description, a dot on its own line sets off a new paragraph. - Most text is word-wrapped, but doubly-indented text is left alone, so you can use it for lists of items, like this list.

Which is apparently not true for substitution.  For example, if you put a space-dot in the template directly it will print a blank line, but put the same in a subst key and it prints the dot. (－‸ლ)

Comment: Thanks for your time on this. I wasn't aware bash scripts let you set a string like that splits over a few lines. I expected an error without it. As I'm used to reading bash scripts that use a backslash to split a command over several llnes.

Comment: I also found putting characters in a substitution didn't work as expected. Be that a space, a dot or even trying to put the needed indented space into the variable.

I did some tests and got some things working but it is too inconsistent. I tested debconf 1.5.42ubuntu1 and could only get one line displayed. I tested debconf 1.5.66ubuntu1 and only one line showed there also.

However, I found, if I disable the db_subst for my description, then the extended description is displayed! But only in the later version.

Comment: I don't want to rely on a later of version of debconf for this and I would be relying on a side effect so unless I'm doing something wrong will need to find another way.

Comment: To split shell _commands_ across multiple lines you have to escape the new line with a backlash at the end, but strings can absolutely span multiple lines.

Comment: I didn’t take into account the debconf version. Perhaps you can use multiple keys like `${extended1}` and `${extended2}` etc. to place each line independently.

Comment: I actually thought about using multiple keys as you suggest. This would likely work fine. The problem is I'm building up a dynamic list so the amount of line is unknown. But, it wouldn't be a huge amount. It could be covered with five extra lines in most cases. I suppose I just don't like lose ends.

Comment: I did find an issue doing it this way which I have encountered earlier while experimenting. All the keys are on the same line. Even with newlines embedded in strings and keys on separate line it still displays them on the same line. :-?

Comment: Hmmm.  I’m not seeing that behavior.  You say you’re building the list dynamically.  Exactly how are you concatenating the extended string?  I’m think that could be your issue.  Make sure you’re using `$'\n'` between the different parts.

Comment: I'm concatenating by doing this:
`item=$(echo "Example item")
extended="${extended}${item}"`

The items are in fact piped from another command where I `grep` and `cut` the relevant sections out I need, so the resulting string has a newline included from the process. The example `echo` above replicating a string with a newline embedded.

Comment: I also tested adding an `example1` to `example3` to the template and filling each with a string with it's own item generated like the `item` in the above comment. So it used multiple keys instead with a `db_subst`. But the result was each string on one line separated by a space. Like this:
`0 1 2 3`

Comment: That's acting almost like you're not quoting the variables.

Comment: If it can't be done consistently from a script then I can only see two options. Appending extra lines to an existing template file that is loaded in after. Or extending the choices with extra information. The latter may be easier as can be done from inside script and doesn't require the user to press "Help" in some Debconf interfaces to see extra information. It is however limited as spaces are trimmed out and therefore harder to organise it as a neatly aligned list.